# passing input data to ng-content from parent in Angular

Tags: angular, ng-content

I have the following structure in a container component (ngrx approach) `container-page.component.ts`

`<parent-comp><child-comp [someInput]="someValue"></child-comp></parent-comp>`

And I in the `parent-comp` template I have

```
<div>
    <!-- some content here -->
    <ng-content></ng-content> <!-- child-comp will go here -->
    <!-- some more content -->
</div>
```

Now passing data from the container to the `child-comp` works fine, but what if I wanted to pass some data from the `parent-comp` to the `child-comp` directly?

doing `<ng-content [inputFromParent]="valueFromParent"></ng-content>` does not work.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I'm following your train of thought. If you already can pass data directly to the child component, why do you want to use `ng-content` as an endpoint for other inputs? Could you provide a use case? Or, even better, a stackblitz demo illustrating what you aren't able to do?

Answer (score 1):

`<ng-content>` cannot have input because it's not a component.  Nor is it a placeholder for a component. It is a placeholder for children.  If `<parent-comp>` had two sibling child components, `<ng-content>` would have to render both of them. The correct way to pass information here would be to use `<parent-comp>`'s parent (the container).  Output someInput from `<parent-comp>` and add it as an Input to to `<child-comp>`